# Can't install Jupyter notebook with pip

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

when I try pip install jupyter, I face this error. what should I do?

```
 WARNING: The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\YOOZBOARD\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\YOOZBOARD\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\jedi\\third_party\\typeshed\\third_party\\2and3\\requests\\packages\\urllib3\\packages\\ssl_match_hostname\\_implementation.pyi'
```

pip install jupyter

Comment: Add the given path to your PATH variable in the system settings. I suppose you are using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `conda update conda` and `pip install --upgrade pip` firstly.

And then if you prefer, you can create a a new virtual environment and try installing Jupyter and other packages there. `conda create --name yourenv`
Then activate your virtual environment: `conda activate yourenv`

You can install jupyter using conda:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Or install Jupyter using pip:

```
pip install jupyter
```

Then within your virtual environment, you can start jupyter notebook by `jupyter notebook`